# Apps' contacts access - one Group only, not ALL contacts. PRIVACY!

Tags: contacts, privacy

Apps (like WhatsApp) that require access to some Contacts, have **no** business knowing and analyzing ALL my contacts.

**How** do I restrict Apps' access to **one group** of contacts, (the group of contacts that I choose to use for that App) only?

Comment: So far as I can tell from years of using iOS, its either **all** contacts or **none**.  As to when you can get more granular with the contacts exposed, you can leave feedback for Apple [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) with your suggestion. We at AskDifferent have no insight into how or why or when Apple will do anything.

Comment: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2021/02/26/clubhouse-wants-to-upload-your-contacts-phone-numbers/

Comment: It's a big gripe for me as well and something that contradicts Apple's otherwise good privacy policy. If you're concerned about privacy I wouldn't be using WhatsApp in first place (it's Facebook owned), but that's a different story. While not ideal, the only "solution" I can think of is to offload contacts in a contacts archive, but that would obviously prevent you from seeing all contacts at any one time.